# How to correctly add a series of time values to an Excel chart

Tags: excel, time, charts, series, vba

I am trying to add a series composed of `Time` values to a chart. The y-axis is formatted as `Time`. I am using the variable `myVal` to hold the value I want to repeat, inside an array, as the series plot values.

I know that `Time` is stored in the `Date` datatype. I am unsure how to how do the correct conversion to add a series to the chart via VBA.

My attempts to assign the series values and plot via code keep resulting in a line being plotted around 0 on the y-axis indicating I have the wrong scale. See red line on chart image.

Chart:

[image: Chart series]

Trying to do conversions on `myVal` with `DateValue("00:07:00")` and `TimeValue("00:07:00")` ,and then scaling, are of no use as they return 0.

I have also seen that there is `FormatDateTime` function, with argument  `vbLongTime`, but I can't see how to apply this in my situation.

I know I can directly add the series from the sheet with :

```
.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = _
        "=ChartDataResponseTimes!$BC$548:$BC$552"
```

Where `$BC$548:$BC$552` is the range, as shown in the image above, containing `"00:07:00"` repeated. This is not the method I want to use as I want to assign the series values via an array within the code.

This, I am certain, is so simple to do, but I am failing miserably today.

Can anyone please solve this?

Code:

```
Sub AddingSeries()

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("hidRTMeanCat1").Chart

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

        .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = _
                                        "=ChartDataResponseTimes!$B$548:$B$552"

        .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
                                         "=ChartDataResponseTimes!$A$548:$A$552"

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

        Dim myVal As Date '**************************************Problem code***************

        myVal = DateValue("00:07:00")

        .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Array(myVal, myVal)

                          '**************************************Problem code***************
    End With

End Sub
```

Note:

`ChartDataResponseTimes!$A$548:$A$552"` is the first column of data in the sample below.

`ChartDataResponseTimes!$B$548:$B$552` is the second column of data in the sample below.

Data sample:

```
| Date   | North West |
|--------|------------|
| Aug-17 | 00:10:07   |
| Sep-17 | 00:09:50   |
| Oct-17 | 00:09:29   |
| Nov-17 | 00:09:44   |
| Dec-17 | 00:11:17   |
```

Comment: Whether you tried to format axis?

Comment: What do you mean? The axis is already formatted as Time. I have a blank chart which I add the series to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  myVal  variable type  to Double.

```
Dim myVal As Double
```

Comment: I get a type mismatch with  Dim myVal As Double :  myVal = CDbl("00:07:00") . Though this sounds like the right thinking.

Comment: @QHarr,  myVal = TimeValue("00:07:00")

Comment: Doh! Back to where i started but had wrong datatype. Thanks so much for sorting.

Comment: @QHarr, Good luck.